# Export to xls using Angular2Csv plugin

Tags: angular, api, export-to-csv

I am trying export my array of data objects coming from api to xls. I am able to export the data using the plugin to xls . But the trick here is to export only selected columns to xls. I have an array of 5 objects coming from api. I need to export only 2 of these to xls. How can i achieve this? I have attached the snapshot of the [![enter image description here][1]][1]generated report with 5 columns, but i need only 2 of these columns. Please suggest.

This is the plugin used : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv

Answer (score 0):

You can export selected column . It is possible. First of all you declare an array. Than extract required column which you want to show from list coming from api and than store them into a variable. After that you use a for loop and push them into arry `  this.lstEmployees = this.employee; // show active employees
          //excelSheet start

```
      for (var i = 0; i < this.lstEmployees.length; i++) {
        this.data.push(
          {
            Item_Description: this.lstEmployees[i].ITM_DES,
            Unit_Of_Measurement: this.lstEmployees[i].UOM_ABR,
            Item_Rate: this.lstEmployees[i].QTD_RTE,
            Item_Price: this.lstEmployees[i].QTY_PRC,
            Item_Quotation: this.lstEmployees[i].QTN_NUM,
            Paymen_type: this.lstEmployees[i].PMT_FLG,
            Tax_Type: this.lstEmployees[i].TAX_FLG,
            Delivery_Type: this.lstEmployees[i].DLV_FLG,
          })

      }`
```

here lstEmployee is the list coming from database and data is and array. Hope you got it